# change detection on video frames

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, frame, python-imaging-library

I have a sequence of actions taking place on a video like, say "zooming in and zooming out" a webpage.
I want to catch the frames that had a visual change from a some previous frame and so on.
Basically, want to catch the visual difference happening in the video.

I have tried using feature detection using SURF. It just detects random frames and does not detect most of the times.
I have also tried, histograms and it does not help.

Any directions and pointers?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

For effects like zooming in and out, optical flow seems the best choice. Search for research papers on "Shot Detection" for other possible approaches.

As for the techniques you mention, did you apply some form of noise reduction before using them?